# Use Jenkins conditionals outside of when{} block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I would like to utilize the built-in Jenkins conditionals that control when a stage is executed in a pipeline. Specifically, I would like to utilize the `changeset` conditional outside of a `when{}` block and store it's truth value into a global variable.

Here is how I would normally use `changeset` :

```
when { changeset "**/pom.xml" }
```

But I would like to assign this value to a global variable like so :

```
GLOBAL_BOOLEAN = changeset "**/pom.xml"
```

Looking at the value assigned, I get this:

```
println(GLOBAL_BOOLEAN)
@changeset(<anonymous>=**/pom.xml)
```

and

```
println(GLOBAL_BOOLEAN.getClass().toString() )
class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.UninstantiatedDescribableWithInterpolation
```

Is there a way to utilize these functions outside a `when{}` block? Thanks

Comment: `changeset` does not return a type that could be converted into something that you would find useful. You would likely need to modify the code into your own library to make this possible.

Comment: Why don't you start with setting a global to `false` and then change it to `true` using a working `when` block?